# http to https redirection of specific pages with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess

I have implemented the following code in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond ${HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(page1\.php|page2\.php)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This redirects page1.php and page2.php to https. However, I want to make sure that if the user navigates to any other page from the https page, they ho to `http://` (and not remain on `https://`).

How can I do this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond ${HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(page1\.php|page2\.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond ${HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^(page1\.php|page2\.php|\.css)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for this.  I have tried implementing this. However, when it gets to the https page, it looks like the stylesheet is being ignored as the page is not layed out at all.  I have looked at the code and the css is being called using a relative path rather than using a http://domain.com/css prefix. Any idea why this may happen?  I will carry on investigating.

Comment: Yes, it's because you redirect the css to http. Use with the second: `RewriteRule !^(page1\.php|page2\.php|css/) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Just to clarify, the last instruction would be: RewriteCond ${HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^(page1\.php|page2\.php|css.)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: Yes, you can add css directory or file type. I add that in my code.